# Group By in SSRS Tablix - Detail on Line Below

Tags: sql-server-2014, ssrs-2008-r2

I am trying to use a Row Group in SSRS to only display certain information from my data set in one row while using the Detail group to display all records from a particular customer.

For the report itself, I have five row groups set up and I am displaying customer records on the Details row group:

[image: Row Grouping]

And the generated report is displaying as expected:

[image: Report Data]

But what I would like to do if possible is to drop the following columns down to a line underneath the TWRA Number / First Name/ Middle Name / Last Name / DOB line like this mock-up in Excel:

[image: Excel Mock-up]

Is this possible in SSRS and if so, any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert a table, on the second row(detail) add the details you require: Date, Licence Type ID, Licence Description etc.....

Right mouse click on the Row Group Details, Add Group, Parent Group, select group by TWRA Number, and select "Add Group Header"

Right mouse click TWRA Number, split cells.

Right mouse Date field, insert Row / inside group above.

First Row will be group labels, second row will be group fields.
Third row will be details labels, fourth row will be details fields.

Picture of design view of report:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.  This worked and I truly appreciate it.